# Infinite scroll not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, infinite-scroll

Below is a infinite scroll or auto load more content script. This code works well in Firefox and opera but does not work in chrome. Though it shows the initial content but when I scroll down the page nothing happens. Why this is not working in chrome ? How can I make it work ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var track_load = 0; 
 var loading  = false; 
 var total_groups = <?=$total_groups;?>;

 $('#results').load("autoload.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

 $(window).scroll(function() { 

 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
 {

  if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) 
  {
    loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
    $('.animation_image').show(); 

    $.post('autoload.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

      $("#results").append(data); 

      //hide loading image
      $('.animation_image').hide(); 

      track_load++; 
      loading = false; 

    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
      alert(thrownError); 
      $('.animation_image').hide(); 
      loading = false;
     });
     }
    }
  });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you opened the chrome debugger, clicked the 'console' tab and checked for errors? Also, have you tried using the "debugger" keyword to step through your code?

Comment: any solution to this problem, me stuck too.